# C++ Iterator ( Next )

Tags: c++, iterator

I have this code that i am using to get an idea of how C++ Next iterator work on key value map that has a struct. I can not think of how:
iter->val happens to be 1 when struct value is 0 for key "test"
next->val happens to be 0

Can someone help me understand this please.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <list>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <unordered_map>
    #include <set>
    #include<unordered_set>
    using namespace std;
    struct test {
        int val;
        unordered_set<string> st;
    };
    
    int main()
    {
      list <test> tst;
      
      unordered_map < string , list<test>::iterator > m;
      
      
       m["test"] = tst.insert(tst.begin() , {0 , {"test"}});
       
       
       auto iter = m["test"] , next = iter++;
       
       
       cout << iter->val << endl;  // prints 1 . Not sure how
       cout << next->val << endl;  // prints 0 not sure how also
       }
```

Comment: dereferencing `std::end(tst)` is UB.

Comment: You have an unordered map of lists of unordered sets? Seems a bit much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first create a struct test with val=0 and st={"test"}. That gets inserted into the list `tst`, so that has one entry now. The return value is an iterator pointing at the new element and is put into m["test"]. So your unordered map has one entry "test" that is an iterator of `tst`. And now the fun begins...

```
   auto iter = m["test"];
```

`iter` becomes a reference to the iterator pointing at the first element of `tst`.

```
   auto next = iter++;
```

Now two things happen: First `next` gets a copy of `iter` and now also points at the first element of `tst`. Secondly `iter` gets incremented (post increment) to point at the next item in the list. Since there are no more it now points to `tst::end()`.

Now lets answer your question of what happens on the output:

```
   cout << iter->val << endl;  // prints 1 . Not sure how
```

This is undefined behavior. You are not allowed to operator->() `end()`. It points to somewhere in memory and randomly that contains 0 so you get 0. Lucky your cat didn't get pregnant.

```
   cout << next->val << endl;  // prints 0 not sure how also
```

Since in practice a little UB does no harm your program continues and accesses `next`. Since `next` points to the first element of `tst` that gets accessed. The first element of `tst` is `{.val = 0; .st={"test"}}` so `next->val` outputs 0.

Are you sure you want a unordered_map of iterators instead of an unordered_map of list?

Answer (score 3):

`cout << iter->val` makes your program have *undefined behavior*. After `iter++` it will be pointing at `tst.end()` and dereferencing `end()` is "illegal".

`cout << next->val` would be ok though since `next` is pointing at the one element that exists in `tst`.